# Icons are disappearing from Plank

Tags: plank, icons

I noticed that some of my icons are randomly disappearing from plank. After a restart, some of my icons are not there. So I have to click again on 'keep in dock' option and it's fine for some time, but after few days it is gone. I think it only happens for applications installed with Snap (spotify, sublime text, slack,...). Any idea why and how to prevent it?